# Scrape image src attribute using pjscrape

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, scraper

I'm having some difficulties with scraping the image source of an image. I tried the following:

```
_pjs.getText('div#customerInfo table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(7) img.attributes.src')
```

as well as

```
_pjs.getText('div#customerInfo table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(7) img[src]')
```

but nothing seems to be working. Is there a way to do this using `getPattern` or maybe another way?

My code is below:

```
 pjs.config({ 
    // options: 'stdout', 'file' (set in config.logFile) or 'none'
    log: 'stdout',
    // options: 'json' or 'csv'
    format: 'json',
    // options: 'stdout' or 'file' (set in config.outFile)
    //writer: 'stdout',
    writer: 'file',
    outFile: 'C:\\pjscrape\\pjscrape_out.txt'
});
pjs.addSuite({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/multivu.portal.htm',
    scraper: function() {
        return [
           _pjs.getText('div#customerInfo table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)'),
           _pjs.getText('div#customerInfo table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)'),
           _pjs.getText('div#customerInfo table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(7) img.attributes.src')
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: I used jQuery and it seems to be working! I am using this:

$("div#customerInfo table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(7) img").attr("src")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery and it seems to be working! I am using this: $("div#customerInfo table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(7) img").attr("src")